# Rails returns an empty active record and failed to initialize the attributes in side the model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting an empty active record when i initialize new model object.

```
2.3.0 :030 > user = User.new
=> #<User > 
2.3.0 :031 >
```

when i access the attributes present in the model it returns an error like

```
2.3.0 :031 > user.UsersName
NoMethodError: undefined method `UsersName' for #<User >
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
    attr_accessible :UserName, :Password, :RoleId, :EmployeeId, :Password_confirmation
end
```

Comment: curious as to why you are using such a back level version of rails? but it should be `user.UseName`, as opposed to `UsersName`.  Below you say it works only on some versions of sql server? Any differences in Sql Server Version, FreeTDS/TinyTDS versions, etc.  If you compare field names between the 2 sql servers are the same (same case, etc..) ActiveRecord Uses introspection to make the fields accessible.  For giggles maybe try `user.user_name` and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure either one of these is true:

1. Your model `User` is inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` and you have a column `UserName` inside your `users` table. Though, by convention, we should not have attribute names started with capital letter.

EDIT- You can skip 'User' from 'UserName' as it is redundant and replace it with `user.name`. For that you should have column `name` inside `users` table and nothing else need to be defined inside model.

2. If above is not the case, then you must have an `attr_accessor :UserName` Or
3. you must have a method `def UserName`. Not sure if capital letters work here.

Also, i suggest you to define all your fields starting with lowercase letters.

Comment: hi Jagdeep, thanks for your help actually i am using sqlserver for DB. The problem is when i connect sqlserver relocated in some where i am getting like this but when i connect sqlserver in my local system is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your model declares that `UserName` is accessible yet you're calling `UsersName` (`user.UsersName`).

Have you tried `user.UserName`?